# MVC Controls and jQuery functions

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a view which renders multiple song category dropdown lists in a ForEach loop.

```
@foreach (var itemCategory in Model)
{
  //Generate unique ids for the category dropdown and assign them.
 @{
      string sCategory = "category" + i;   
 }
 @Html.DropDownListFor(itemCategory.categoryName , itemCategory.songslist, new {@Id=sCategory})
 }
```

Example: The above ID's would be category0 to category4

I am trying to find individual values selected from each category dropdown using change event. But the below script does not work.

JavaScript/jQuery :

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

$(function () {

        var totalCategories = 5            
        for (i = 0; i < totalCategories ; i++) {

                 $('#category' + i)
                   .change(function () {
                       var str = "";
                       str = $('#category' + i).children('option:selected').val();
                       alert(str);
                   })
                   .change();

        }
});

</script>
```

This works when I have only one dropdown but how do I make it to work with multiple dropdowns created dynamically?

Any help or suggestions please.

Comment: what is "i" in your foreach loop??

Comment: Check whether the dropdowns have the id category0, category1, etc in html source

Comment: I used "i" to call the change event to specific drop downs.

Comment: I do see the id correctly in HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe don't be so specific with your selector, you can assign the same code to all dropdowns without knowing their ID, like:

```
$( "select" )
  .change(function () {
    var str = "";
    $(this).find( "option:selected" ).each(function() {
      str += $( this ).text() + " ";
    });
    alert(str);
  }) ;
```

From http://api.jquery.com/change/

EDIT:

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NFmS8/1/

Comment: I tried this code first but it picks the selected values from other drop-downs too.

Comment: @user3479754 I've updated the code and included a working fiddle.

Comment: Hi Shenku: Your solution worked perfectly for me.  One minor change I made was pass e into the function and use  e.target.name to get the name of the select drop down. Thanks for you help.